# Can I always assume that a vapour pressure over a liquid is ideal?

Tags: ideal-gas, evaporation

Can I assume that the vapour of a subject over its liquid is ideal-ish?

I'm thinking that if the vapour pressure is low the subject in question wont interact with itself, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the subject wont have interactive forces with air, does it?

For context:

The question was formed shile solving a question for a course on chemical thermodynamics in which I used clausius-clapeyron equation to find the heat of vaporization of $Tc_2O_7$. In that case it turns out i could assume the vapour was ideal.

I feel like I had no way of knowing other than by knowing that the question was in the Clausius-Clapeyron section and this course doesn't include using Clausius-Clapeyron with non-ideal gases.

Comment: what do you mean by ideal? with respect to Raoult's law? also pure liquid or solution?

Comment: ideal as in no interaction between gas molecules, I want to use ideal gas law. Pure liquid.

Comment: interactions between molecules of gas can be ignored when pressure or density is not high

Comment: But if all i know is the partial pressure of the vapour then there migth be air there too that might interact with the gas. When using the ideal gas law, am i assuming that there is no air there?

Comment: actually ideal gas law is a good approx for air at atmospheric pressure as well

Comment: So, in summary, if a gas itself is acting ideal then air will never make it act non-ideal?

Comment: in my knowledge no but you should note that this is not binary. it's a good approximation which gets worse with high pressure/density